# Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061) on rails for windows 10

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, activerecord, rubygems, mysql2

I'm currently working on a project and quite new to rails. I'm facing an issue regarding on "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)". 
I have been trying for days but the error is still the same. 
I have followed this guide from: https://medium.com/ruby-on-rails-web-application-development/installing-the-mysql2-rubyonrails-gem-on-windows-7-8-a028f44d87f3 where I installed it using MSYS2/RubyInstaller2 through cmd. Everything is same as the guide with all the version, but I am still having the same error.

The error occurred when I go to http://localhost:3000/ in my database.yml
I try changing the localhost 127.0.0.1 and it still does not work. When I entered mysql.server start in cmd, is just says "'mysql.server' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

Do I have to install an external file for it to run? Really need some help. Thank you.

Version:
Rails 5.2.2, ruby 2.6.6p146 (2020-03-31 revision 67876) [x64-mingw32] and mysql2 (0.5.3)

Error:

```
Mysql2::Error::ConnectionError (Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)):

mysql2-0.5.3-x64 (mingw32) lib/mysql2/client.rb:90:in `connect'
mysql2-0.5.3-x64 (mingw32) lib/mysql2/client.rb:90:in `initialize'
activerecord (5.2.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:22:in `new'
activerecord (5.2.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:22:in `mysql2_connection'
activerecord (5.2.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:811:in `new_connection'
activerecord (5.2.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:855:in `checkout_new_connection'
activerecord (5.2.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:834:in `try_to_checkout_new_connection'
activerecord (5.2.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:795:in `acquire_connection'
activerecord (5.2.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:523:in `checkout'
activerecord (5.2.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:382:in `connection'
activerecord (5.2.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:1010:in `retrieve_connection'
activerecord (5.2.2) lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:118:in `retrieve_connection'
activerecord (5.2.2) lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:90:in `connection'
activerecord (5.2.2) lib/active_record/migration.rb:554:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:98:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (5.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:61:in `call'
web-console (3.7.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:135:in `call_app'
web-console (3.7.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:30:in `block in call'
web-console (3.7.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:20:in `catch'
web-console (3.7.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:33:in `call'
railties (5.2.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (5.2.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.2.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:71:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (5.2.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:28:in `tagged'
activesupport (5.2.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:71:in `tagged'
railties (5.2.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:81:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:27:in `call'
rack (2.2.2) lib/rack/method_override.rb:24:in `call'
rack (2.2.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
activesupport (5.2.2) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:29:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:127:in `call'
rack (2.2.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:110:in `call'
railties (5.2.2) lib/rails/engine.rb:524:in `call'
puma (3.11.0) lib/puma/configuration.rb:225:in `call'
puma (3.11.0) lib/puma/server.rb:624:in `handle_request'
puma (3.11.0) lib/puma/server.rb:438:in `process_client'
puma (3.11.0) lib/puma/server.rb:302:in `block in run'
puma (3.11.0) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

database.yml:

```
default: &default
  adapter: sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  #database: db/development.sqlite3
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: localdb
  host: localhost
  username: root
  password: test

test:
  <<: *default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: <%= ENV['RDS_DB_NAME'] %>
  username: <%= ENV['RDS_USERNAME'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['RDS_PASSWORD'] %>
  host: <%= ENV['RDS_HOSTNAME'] %> 
  port: <%= ENV['RDS_PORT'] %>

production:
  <<: *default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: <%= ENV['RDS_DB_NAME'] %>
  username: <%= ENV['RDS_USERNAME'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['RDS_PASSWORD'] %>
  host: <%= ENV['RDS_HOSTNAME'] %> 
  port: <%= ENV['RDS_PORT'] %>
  pool: 50 #20
  timeout: 10000
```